# Automatically remove broken packages in preparation for upgrade?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 and want to upgrade to 18.10 so I can later upgrade to 19. However, it fails with the message

```
Calculating the changes

Could not calculate the upgrade 

An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade.
```

Looking into the log file `/var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log` reveals the following problem: 
`ERROR Dist-upgrade failed: 'E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.'`

The list of broken packages that comes out of `grep Broken /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log` is quite long. Most of the entries seem to be related to `python-3` although I don't know why and what the significance of that is. Here's the grepped log output:

```
Broken python3:amd64 Depends on python3.7:amd64 < none | 3.7.3-2ubuntu0.2 @un uH > (>= 3.7.3-1~)
Broken python3-gi:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.6.7-1~18.04 | 3.7.3-1 @ii umR > (< 3.8)
Broken python3-minimal:amd64 PreDepends on python3.7-minimal:amd64 < none | 3.7.3-2ubuntu0.2 @un uH > (>= 3.7.3-1~)
Broken gnome-shell:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.6.7-1~18.04 | 3.7.3-1 @ii umR >
Broken lsb-release:amd64 Depends on python3:any:any < none @un H >
Broken python3-dbus:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.6.7-1~18.04 | 3.7.3-1 @ii umR > (< 3.8)
Broken python3-apt:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.6.7-1~18.04 | 3.7.3-1 @ii umR > (< 3.8)
Broken libboost1.67-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost1.65-dev:amd64 < 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5 -> 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu11 @ii umU >
Broken python3-six:amd64 Depends on python3:any:any < none @un H >
Broken python3-pkg-resources:amd64 Depends on python3:any:any < none @un H >
Broken python3-distro-info:amd64 Depends on python3:any:any < none @un H >
Broken ibus:amd64 Depends on python3-gi:amd64 < 3.26.1-2ubuntu1 | 3.32.0-1 @ii umR >
Broken python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets:amd64 Depends on python3:any:any < none @un H > (>= 3.2~)
Broken python3-yaml:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.6.7-1~18.04 | 3.7.3-1 @ii umR > (< 3.8)
Broken python3-distro:amd64 Depends on lsb-release:amd64 < 9.20170808ubuntu1 | 10.2019031300ubuntu1 @ii umR >
Broken gdm3:amd64 Depends on gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.28.4-0ubuntu18.04.2 | 3.32.2-2ubuntu1~ubuntu19.04.1 @ii umR > (>= 3.19.92)
Broken python3-distupgrade:amd64 Depends on python3:any:any < none @un H >
Broken software-properties-gtk:amd64 Depends on python3:any:any < none @un H >
Broken ubuntu-session:amd64 Depends on gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.28.4-0ubuntu18.04.2 | 3.32.2-2ubuntu1~ubuntu19.04.1 @ii umR > (>= 3.24.3-0ubuntu2)
Broken python3-update-manager:amd64 Depends on python3:any:any < none @un H > (>= 3.2~)
Broken networkd-dispatcher:amd64 Depends on python3-dbus:amd64 < 1.2.6-1 | 1.2.8-3 @ii umR >
Broken update-manager-core:amd64 Depends on python3:any:any < none @un H > (>= 3.2~)
Broken python3-chardet:amd64 Depends on python3:any:any < none @un H >
Broken python3-urllib3:amd64 Depends on python3:any:any < none @un H >
Broken python3-cups:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.6.7-1~18.04 | 3.7.3-1 @ii umR > (< 3.8)
Broken ubuntu-release-upgrader-core:amd64 Depends on python3:any:any < none @un H >
Broken python3-aptdaemon:amd64 Depends on python3:any:any < none @un H > (>= 3.2~)
Broken plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text:amd64 Depends on lsb-release:amd64 < 9.20170808ubuntu1 | 10.2019031300ubuntu1 @ii umR >

<snip>

Broken mono-devel:amd64 Breaks on mono-reference-assemblies-4.0:amd64 < 3.12.1+dfsg-2 @ii mK > (< 5.0~)
Broken totem-plugins:amd64 Depends on python3-gi:amd64 < 3.26.1-2ubuntu1 | 3.32.0-1 @ii umR > (>= 2.90.3)
Broken python3-olefile:amd64 Depends on python3:any:any < none @un H >
Broken libboost-test1.67-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-test1.65-dev:amd64 < 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5 -> 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu11 @ii umU Ib >
Broken ubuntu-software:amd64 Depends on gnome-software:amd64 < 3.28.1-0ubuntu4.18.04.12 | 3.30.6-2ubuntu4.19.04.2 @ii umR > (>= 3.30.6-2ubuntu4.19.04.2)
Broken openprinting-ppds:amd64 Depends on python3:any:any < none @un H >
Broken libboost-thread1.67-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-thread1.65-dev:amd64 < 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5 -> 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu11 @ii umU Ib >
Broken python3-reportlab-accel:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.6.7-1~18.04 | 3.7.3-1 @ii umR > (< 3.8)
Broken printer-driver-sag-gdi:amd64 Depends on python3:any:any < none @un H >
Broken libboost-regex1.67-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-regex1.65-dev:amd64 < 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5 -> 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu11 @ii umU Ib >
Broken usb-creator-common:amd64 Depends on python3:any:any < none @un H > (>= 3.2~)
Broken python3-secretstorage:amd64 Depends on python3-dbus:amd64 < 1.2.6-1 | 1.2.8-3 @ii umR >
Broken python3-brlapi:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.6.7-1~18.04 | 3.7.3-1 @ii umR > (< 3.8)
Broken python3-protobuf:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.6.7-1~18.04 | 3.7.3-1 @ii umR > (< 3.8)
Broken libnvidia-compute-390:amd64 Conflicts on libcuda-5.0-1:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken libnvidia-compute-390:amd64 Conflicts on libcuda-5.5-1:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken libnvidia-compute-390:amd64 Conflicts on libcuda-6.0-1:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken libnvidia-compute-390:amd64 Conflicts on libcuda-6.5-1:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken libnvidia-compute-390:amd64 Conflicts on libcuda-7.0-1:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken libnvidia-compute-390:amd64 Conflicts on libcuda-7.5-1:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken libnvidia-compute-390:amd64 Conflicts on libcuda-8.0-1:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken libnvidia-compute-390:amd64 Conflicts on libcuda-9.0-1:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken libnvidia-compute-390:amd64 Conflicts on libcuda-9.1-1:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken libnvidia-compute-390:amd64 Conflicts on nvidia-opencl-icd:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock:amd64 Depends on gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.28.4-0ubuntu18.04.2 | 3.32.2-2ubuntu1~ubuntu19.04.1 @ii umR > (< 3.33)
Broken orca:amd64 Depends on python3:any:any < none @un H > (>= 3.3~)
Broken python3-lazr.restfulclient:amd64 Depends on python3-httplib2:amd64 < 0.9.2+dfsg-1ubuntu0.1 | 0.11.3-2 @ii umR > (>= 0.7.7)
Broken ubuntu-standard:amd64 Depends on language-selector-common:amd64 < 0.188.3 | 0.194.1 @ii umR >
Broken firefox:amd64 Depends on lsb-release:amd64 < 9.20170808ubuntu1 | 10.2019031300ubuntu1 @ii umR >
Broken python3-mako:amd64 Depends on python3:any:any < none @un H > (>= 3.3.2-2~)
Broken printer-driver-pxljr:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.6.7-1~18.04 | 3.7.3-1 @ii umR >
Broken python3-speechd:amd64 Depends on python3-xdg:amd64 < 0.25-4ubuntu1 | 0.25-5 @ii umR >
Broken apturl-common:amd64 Depends on python3:any:any < none @un H > (>= 3.2~)
Broken python3-tz:amd64 Depends on python3:any:any < none @un H >

<snip>

Broken libatk1.0-dev:amd64 Depends on libglib2.0-dev:amd64 < 2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.4 | 2.60.4-0ubuntu0.19.04.1 @ii umR > (>= 2.31.2)
Broken libpango1.0-dev:amd64 Depends on libcairo2-dev:amd64 < 1.15.10-2ubuntu0.1 | 1.16.0-4 @ii umR > (>= 1.12.10)
Broken libgtk2.0-dev:amd64 Depends on libglib2.0-dev:amd64 < 2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.4 | 2.60.4-0ubuntu0.19.04.1 @ii umR > (>= 2.27.3)
Broken libboost-all-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost-mpi-python-dev:amd64 < 1.65.1.0ubuntu1 | 1.67.0.1 @ii umR >
Broken libicu-le-hb-dev:amd64 Depends on libharfbuzz-dev:amd64 < 1.7.2-1ubuntu1 | 2.3.1-1 @ii umR >
Broken gnome-user-guide:amd64 Depends on gnome-user-docs:amd64 < 3.28.2+git20180715-0ubuntu0.1 | 3.32.0+git20190406-0ubuntu1 @ii umR >
Broken libboost-python1.65-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost1.65-dev:amd64 < 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5 | 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu11 @ii umR > (= 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5)
Broken gnome-control-center:amd64 Depends on language-selector-gnome:amd64 < 0.188.3 | 0.194.1 @ii umR > (>= 0.179~)
Broken gnome-control-center:amd64 Depends on system-config-printer:amd64 < 1.5.11-1ubuntu2 | 1.5.11-2ubuntu2 @ii umR > (>= 1.4)
Broken snapd:amd64 Depends on apparmor:amd64 < 2.12-4ubuntu5.1 | 2.13.2-9ubuntu6.1 @ii umR > (>= 2.10.95-0ubuntu2.2)
Broken libsmbclient:amd64 Depends on samba-libs:amd64 < 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.13 | 2:4.10.0+dfsg-0ubuntu2.6 @ii umR > (= 2:4.10.0+dfsg-0ubuntu2.6)
Broken apparmor:amd64 Depends on python3:any:any < none @un H >
Broken libpython3.7-stdlib:amd64 Depends on libpython3.7-minimal:amd64 < 3.7.5-2~18.04 @ii mR > (= 3.7.5-2~18.04)
Broken libpython3.7-minimal:i386 Breaks on libpython3.7-minimal:amd64 < 3.7.5-2~18.04 @ii mK Ib > (!= 3.7.3-2ubuntu0.2)
Broken system-config-printer:amd64 Depends on python3-cups:amd64 < 1.9.73-2 | 1.9.73-2build2 @ii umR > (>= 1.9.60)
Broken system-config-printer:amd64 Depends on python3-cupshelpers:amd64 < 1.5.11-1ubuntu2 | 1.5.11-2ubuntu2 @ii umR > (= 1.5.11-1ubuntu2)
Broken system-config-printer:amd64 Depends on python3-dbus:amd64 < 1.2.6-1 | 1.2.8-3 @ii umR >
Broken language-selector-gnome:amd64 Depends on language-selector-common:amd64 < 0.188.3 | 0.194.1 @ii umR > (= 0.188.3)
Broken language-selector-gnome:amd64 Depends on python3:any:any < none @un H > (>= 3.3.2-2~)
Broken python3.7-minimal:i386 Depends on libpython3.7-minimal:i386 < none | 3.7.3-2ubuntu0.2 @un uH > (= 3.7.3-2ubuntu0.2)
Broken libboost-python-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost-python1.65-dev:amd64 < 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5 | 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu11 @ii umR >
Broken libboost-python1.65-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost1.65-dev:amd64 < 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5 | 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu11 @ii umR > (= 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5)
Broken gnome-control-center:amd64 Depends on libsmbclient:amd64 < 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.13 | 2:4.10.0+dfsg-0ubuntu2.6 @ii umR > (>= 2:4.0.3+dfsg1)
Broken gnome-control-center:amd64 Depends on language-selector-gnome:amd64 < 0.188.3 | 0.194.1 @ii umR > (>= 0.179~)
Broken gvfs-backends:amd64 Depends on libsmbclient:amd64 < 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.13 | 2:4.10.0+dfsg-0ubuntu2.6 @ii umR > (>= 2:4.10.0+dfsg)
Broken snapd:amd64 Depends on apparmor:amd64 < 2.12-4ubuntu5.1 | 2.13.2-9ubuntu6.1 @ii umR > (>= 2.10.95-0ubuntu2.2)
Broken libboost-python-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost-python1.65-dev:amd64 < 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5 | 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu11 @ii umR >
Broken python3:amd64 Depends on python3.7:amd64 < none | 3.7.3-2ubuntu0.2 @un uH > (>= 3.7.3-1~)
Broken python3-minimal:amd64 PreDepends on python3.7-minimal:amd64 < none | 3.7.3-2ubuntu0.2 @un uH > (>= 3.7.3-1~)
Broken lsb-release:amd64 Depends on python3:any:any < none @un H >
Broken python3-yaml:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.6.7-1~18.04 | 3.7.3-1 @ii umR > (< 3.8)
Broken python3-netifaces:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.6.7-1~18.04 | 3.7.3-1 @ii umR > (< 3.8)
Broken netplan.io:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.6.7-1~18.04 | 3.7.3-1 @ii umR >
Broken ubuntu-minimal:amd64 Depends on lsb-release:amd64 < 9.20170808ubuntu1 | 10.2019031300ubuntu1 @ii umR >
Broken ubuntu-minimal:amd64 Depends on netplan.io:amd64 < 0.98-0ubuntu1~18.04.1 | 0.98-0ubuntu1~19.04.1 @ii umR >
Broken ubuntu-minimal:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.6.7-1~18.04 | 3.7.3-1 @ii umR >
Broken python3:amd64 Depends on libpython3-stdlib:amd64 < 3.6.7-1~18.04 -> 3.7.3-1 @ii umU > (= 3.6.7-1~18.04)
Broken netplan.io:amd64 Depends on python3-yaml:amd64 < 3.12-1build2 | 3.13-2 @ii umR >
Broken ubuntu-minimal:amd64 Depends on netplan.io:amd64 < 0.98-0ubuntu1~18.04.1 | 0.98-0ubuntu1~19.04.1 @ii umR >
Broken netplan.io:amd64 Depends on python3-yaml:amd64 < 3.12-1build2 | 3.13-2 @ii umR >
Broken netplan.io:amd64 Depends on python3-netifaces:amd64 < 0.10.4-0.1build4 | 0.10.4-1build2 @ii umR >
Broken python3:amd64 Depends on python3.7:amd64 < none | 3.7.3-2ubuntu0.2 @un uH > (>= 3.7.3-1~)
Broken lsb-release:amd64 Depends on python3:any:any < none @un H >
Broken python3-minimal:amd64 PreDepends on python3.7-minimal:amd64 < none | 3.7.3-2ubuntu0.2 @un uH > (>= 3.7.3-1~)
Broken python3-apt:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.6.7-1~18.04 | 3.7.3-1 @ii umR > (< 3.8)
Broken python3-distro-info:amd64 Depends on python3:any:any < none @un H >
Broken python3-update-manager:amd64 Depends on python3:any:any < none @un H > (>= 3.2~)
Broken plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text:amd64 Depends on lsb-release:amd64 < 9.20170808ubuntu1 | 10.2019031300ubuntu1 @ii umR >
Broken python3-distupgrade:amd64 Depends on python3:any:any < none @un H >
Broken update-manager-core:amd64 Depends on python3:any:any < none @un H > (>= 3.2~)
Broken python3-gi:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.6.7-1~18.04 | 3.7.3-1 @ii umR > (< 3.8)
Broken python3-dbus:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.6.7-1~18.04 | 3.7.3-1 @ii umR > (< 3.8)
Broken ubuntu-release-upgrader-core:amd64 Depends on python3:any:any < none @un H >
Broken python3-gdbm:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.6.7-1~18.04 | 3.7.3-1 @ii umR > (>= 3.7.1-1~)
Broken python3-commandnotfound:amd64 Depends on lsb-release:amd64 < 9.20170808ubuntu1 | 10.2019031300ubuntu1 @ii umR >
Broken apparmor:amd64 Depends on python3:any:any < none @un H >
Broken command-not-found:amd64 Depends on python3-commandnotfound:amd64 < 18.04.5 | 18.10.0~pre2 @ii umR > (= 18.10.0~pre2)
Broken language-selector-common:amd64 Depends on python3:any:any < none @un H >
Broken ufw:amd64 Depends on python3:any:any < none @un H >
Broken python3-netifaces:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.6.7-1~18.04 | 3.7.3-1 @ii umR > (< 3.8)
Broken python3-yaml:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.6.7-1~18.04 | 3.7.3-1 @ii umR > (< 3.8)
Broken ubuntu-minimal:amd64 Depends on lsb-release:amd64 < 9.20170808ubuntu1 | 10.2019031300ubuntu1 @ii umR >
Broken netplan.io:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.6.7-1~18.04 | 3.7.3-1 @ii umR >
Broken ubuntu-standard:amd64 Depends on language-selector-common:amd64 < 0.188.3 | 0.194.1 @ii umR >
Broken language-selector-common:amd64 Depends on python3:any:any < none @un H > (>= 3.3.2-2~)
Broken ubuntu-minimal:amd64 Depends on lsb-release:amd64 < 9.20170808ubuntu1 | 10.2019031300ubuntu1 @ii umR >
Broken ubuntu-standard:amd64 Depends on language-selector-common:amd64 < 0.188.3 | 0.194.1 @ii umR >
Broken language-selector-common:amd64 Depends on python3:any:any < none @un H > (>= 3.3.2-2~)
Broken language-selector-common:amd64 Depends on python3-apt:amd64 < 1.6.4 | 1.8.4 @ii umR > (>= 0.7.12.0)
Broken language-selector-common:amd64 Depends on python3-dbus:amd64 < 1.2.6-1 | 1.2.8-3 @ii umR >
Broken ubuntu-minimal:amd64 Depends on lsb-release:amd64 < 9.20170808ubuntu1 | 10.2019031300ubuntu1 @ii umR >
Broken python3:amd64 Depends on libpython3-stdlib:amd64 < 3.6.7-1~18.04 -> 3.7.3-1 @ii umU > (= 3.6.7-1~18.04)
Broken ubuntu-minimal:amd64 Depends on lsb-release:amd64 < 9.20170808ubuntu1 | 10.2019031300ubuntu1 @ii umR >
Broken ubuntu-minimal:amd64 Depends on lsb-release:amd64 < 9.20170808ubuntu1 | 10.2019031300ubuntu1 @ii umR >
Broken ubuntu-minimal:amd64 Depends on lsb-release:amd64 < 9.20170808ubuntu1 | 10.2019031300ubuntu1 @ii umR >
Broken ubuntu-minimal:amd64 Depends on lsb-release:amd64 < 9.20170808ubuntu1 | 10.2019031300ubuntu1 @ii umR >
Broken ubuntu-minimal:amd64 Depends on lsb-release:amd64 < 9.20170808ubuntu1 | 10.2019031300ubuntu1 @ii umR >
Broken ubuntu-minimal:amd64 Depends on lsb-release:amd64 < 9.20170808ubuntu1 | 10.2019031300ubuntu1 @ii umR >
Broken ubuntu-minimal:amd64 Depends on lsb-release:amd64 < 9.20170808ubuntu1 | 10.2019031300ubuntu1 @ii umR >
```

Here's the whole log output for the broken packages: https://gist.github.com/douira/b1050e442f868127fbadb5c353205cf6

Do I really need to remove all of these individually? Isn't there a way to just remove all of them? Do they really all need to be removed? I can't imagine python needing to be removed since I expect it to be installable on the newer version too...

Comment: "Broken" does NOT mean that the package is corrupt or non-functional. It means that the *resolver* has broken due to a logical impossibility. You "fix" the broken packages by resolving the logical impasse.  Usually it means that you have unwisely added a non-Ubuntu, PPA, or wrong-release source that provides packages that are incompatible with your system. The way you fix the logical impasse is by deleting that source AND uninstalling all packages from that source.

Comment: I'll recommend to wait for 20.04 LTS and upgrade to it. Upgrading to non-LTS does not have any trade-offs IMHO.